# Best way to use npm and git?

Tags: git, version-control, npm

I'm quite new to both git and npm, but I understand the basics, at least I think I understand.
Anyway I will describe the way I'm thinking to work, but I think there are better ways to do.

- I create the root folder with my node.js module.
- I add the package.json file and configure the name and the version.
- `git init` in this root folder.
- Then `git add .` to add all the files to the source control.
- Commit it. This would be my version 0.0.1. I don't know how to set this in the git.
- `npm publish`
- And this is all for the first cycle.

Now for the next little change, not version:

- I change a file.
- I change the version in package.json to 0.0.2.
- I `git commit`.
- done.
- Same for other little changes, but don't change the version.

Now for the next version change:

- I change the files
- I change the version to the next.
- I git commit.

I would need some reference between the npm version and git version. How to do it?

Comment: what are the best-practices to use git with npm?

Comment: You don't need to keep changing the version with every little change; commit as often as you like, and then bump the version in `package.json` up when it's time to `npm publish` again. You can use `git tag` to record which commit that occurred at.

Comment: You will need to `npm publish` again when you want the changes you've commited to be `npm install`able by the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best practise is to add

```
node_modules/*
```

to `.gitignore` :)

git is source control system and npm is package managment, ignore stuff like native packages that you use and thats all all the resto or "real" code has to go to module. Also if you have any config files like `database.json` put thme into ignore and put into repo sample like `database.json.sample`

Thats it! :>

You change npm package verison only when you have few comits and feature changes :) so it is exclusive.

Comment: at the moment I'm building a project where have 3 different folders: client, server and shared. The reason I use them is because I use qooxdoo (http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/Reusing-server-side-code-in-the-client-side-amp-amp-how-to-get-rid-of-the-require-in-nodejs-suggestin-td7452919.html). In this way the 3 folders will be separately managed by git, the shared and the server folders will also be managed by npm. It's becoming a little bit confusing and maybe overkill. What's your opinion?

Comment: Overkill. If you have "shared" folder between two apps it almost always ends up in versioning hell.

Comment: then what I do? I don't want to end up writting the same code too. Maybe it's better to include the 3 folders together and then gitversion them together, right? then I would have the same version for both 3 folders. npm version for shared and server might not always be the same to.